# Querying JSONB array value for sub values?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSONB Object:

```
{"name": "Foo", "interfaces": [{"name": "Bar", "status": "up"}]}
```

It is stored in a jsonb column of a table

```
create table device (
  device_name character varying not null,
  device_data jsonb not null
);
```

So i was trying to get a count by name of devices which have interfaces that are not 'up'.  Group By is used for developing counts by naame, but i am having issues querying the json list for values.

MY first Attempt was:

```
select device_name, count(*) from device where device_json -> 'interfaces' -> 'status' != 'up' group by device_name;
```

Some surrounding data that made me think something was going to be difficult was:

```
select count(device_data -> 'interfaces') from device;
```

which I thought that was going to get me a count of all interfaces from all devices, but that is not correct.  It seems like it is just returning the count from the first item.

Im thinking I might need to do a sub query or join of inner content.

Ive been thinking it over and when looking up psql it seems like i havent found a way to query a list type in a jsonb object.  Maybe im mistaken.  I didnt want to build a business layer on top of this as I figured that the DBMS would be able to handle this heavy lifting.

I saw there is a function *jsonb_array_elements_text(device_data -> 'interfaces')::jsonb -> 'status'* which would return the information, but I cant do any sort of count in it, as `count(jsonb_array_elements_text(device_data -> 'interfaces')::jsonb -> 'status')` will return *ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set*

Comment: What if your array contains multiple interface names? E.g. two that are up and three that are down?

Comment: I am trying to get a count of 'down' essentially.  So for each row/device, I would know how many interfaces are down.

Comment: So if one device has two interfaces up and three down you want that device listed with a count of three?

Comment: You are correct.  I dont know if it would be more difficult to do:  device_name, count(ALL INTERFACES), count(DOWN INTERFACE based on STATUS property), but at min, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lateral join to unnest the array and count the elements that are down (or not up)

```
select d.device_name, t.num_down
from device d
  cross join lateral (
     select count(*) num_down
     from jsonb_array_elements(d.device_data -> 'interfaces') as x(i)
     where i ->> 'status' = 'down'
  ) t
```

To count all interfaces and the down interfaces, you can use filtered aggregation:

```
select d.device_name, t.*
from device d
  cross join lateral (
     select count(*) as all_interfaces,
            count(*) filter (where i ->> 'status' = 'down') as down_interfaces
     from jsonb_array_elements(d.device_data -> 'interfaces') as x(i)
  ) t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=89a61f5f216e8ab36d9ebb7dcb5e3de4)

Comment: I was thinking a join and *unnest* here would likely be the be best course of action.  Is there a timer within the DBMS, i want to test runtimes of yours vs Bergi's

Comment: @Fallenreaper: compare the results of `explain (analyze) select ...`. But bergi's second statement is essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use-case for if device_data is saved as an empty object?  It looks like it is a soft error when accessing the interfaces property and would act as if the array is of size 0?

Comment: They are very similar indeed.  Looks like the difference over the dataset i have is only 6.5ms.  Fantastic

Comment: @Fallenreaper: not sure what you mean, nothing changes if the JSON is empty: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c2b994dd6a30ab303f2bc4bae775ce93

Answer (score 1):

`jsonb_array_elements` is the right idea, I think you are looking for an `EXISTS` condition to match your description "*devices which have interfaces that are not 'up'*":

```
SELECT device_name, count(*)
FROM device
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(device_json -> 'interfaces') interface
  WHERE interface ->> 'status' != 'up')
GROUP BY device_name;
```

> I would like to know how many interfaces are down

That's a different problem, for this you could use a subquery in the `SELECT` clause, and probably wouldn't need to do any grouping:

```
SELECT
  device_name,
  ( SELECT count(*)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(device_json -> 'interfaces') interface
    WHERE interface ->> 'status' != 'up'
  ) AS down_count
FROM device
```

Comment: My goal is on a per device basis.  It looks like the exists command will assume plausibly discern that if a device has ANY non-up status interfaces that it should be reported.  My goal is to get a total list of devicenames and the count of the interfaces under each device which aren't up.  If that makes sense?  Granted.  Having a select which will return a list of devices which have at least 1 down interface sounds also very useful

Comment: Is there a built in DBMS too to time selects?  now(): [select]; now() or something?